# Is l'hopital's rule the only way to answer this question involving $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{x^3}$?

Tags: limits

Is l'hopital's rule the only way to solve this problem?

> If  $$
>       \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{x^3}=\frac{m}{p!}
>     $$
> then evaluate $mp$.
> Given that,m and p are positive integers

Comment: are you sure it is $x^5$ in the denominator and not $x^3$? As written the limit is $\infty$.

Comment: thank you, the problem makes sense to me now

Comment: The product $mp$ is not determined. For example, $m=60$ and $p=5$ give $mp=300$, while $m=1$ and $p=2$ give $mp=2$; in both cases, $m/p!=\frac12$.

Comment: the options given included 0, 1, 2, 7. So the answer would be 2

Comment: what did those numbers correspond to?

Comment: the value of mp

Comment: even that is ambiguous given that we don't know what $m,p$ are. if we don't restrict them to integers, we could take $m=1/2,p=0$, then $mp=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} {\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{x^3}} = \frac{m}{p!}$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0} {\frac{\sin x({\sec x-1})}{x^3}} = \frac{m}{p!}$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0} {\frac{({\sec x-1})}{x^2}} = \frac{m}{p!}$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0} {\frac{({1-\cos x})}{x^2\cos x}} = \frac{m}{p!}$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0} {\frac{({2\sin^2{\frac{x}{2}}})}{x^2\cos x}} = \frac{m}{p!}$$
$$2\lim_{x \to 0} {\frac{({\sin^2{\frac{x}{2}}})}{\frac{x^2}{4}.4\cos x}} = \frac{m}{p!}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0} {\frac{1}{\cos x}} = \frac{m}{p!}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{m}{p!}. $$

$$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{m(p+1)}{p!(p+1)}$$
$$\frac{(p+1)!}{2}=mp+m$$
$$\frac{(p+1)!}{2}-m=mp$$

Comment: what about $m=12, p=4$? or $m=60,p=5$? edit: you could even take $m=1/2,p=0$

Comment: Right, so there probably are a lot of solutions...Thaanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\frac{\tan(x)-\sin(x)}{x^3}=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\cdot\left[\frac{1}{\cos(x)}-1\right]\cdot\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\cdot\left[\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\cos(x)}\right]\cdot\frac{1}{x^2}$$
which simplifies to
$$\frac{\tan(x)}{x}\cdot\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}$$
Recalling that $\sin(x)\tan(x/2)=1-\cos(x)$ from the tangent half-angle formula, we see that it reduces further to
$$\frac{\tan(x)}{x}\cdot\frac{\sin(x)\tan(x/2)}{x^2}=\frac{\tan(x)}{x}\cdot\frac{\tan(x/2)}{x/2}\cdot\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$$

Since we have $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan(x/2)}{x/2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$$
we see that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan(x)-\sin(x)}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan(x)}{x}\cdot\frac{\tan(x/2)}{x/2}\cdot\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$
hence $$\frac{m}{p!}=\frac{1}{2}\Longrightarrow 2m=p!\Longrightarrow mp=\frac{p\cdot p!}{2} $$

Comment: Actually, m and p can take two values, they are $m=1,p=2$, and $m=3,p=3$

Comment: @SmritiSivakumar yea i just realized that I can't conclude that $m=2,p=1$. making edits right now